# How can I manage memory better in Excel VBA to prevent macro from slowing down?

Tags: performance, vba, excel

### Background

I inherited quite a bit of Excel VBA code that was wonky and ran slowly.  The code simulates user input into a report thousands of times and then generates an output file to be sent to some other users.  I made great strides in performance thus far by eliminating copy/paste, by working within arrays instead of accessing the sheets and cells directly, by removing unnecessary code, and by re-working many volatile formulas into something better.

Prior to my changes, running this report to simulate user input would take around 65 seconds per user (and there are roughly 4,300 users).  That comes out to 279,500 seconds (roughly 77.6 hours).  That is assuming a constant speed, the same speed at which the macro begins.  This is not the case at all.  In reality, the macro slows considerably as it processes overnight and on, to the point where it is taking well over 120 seconds per user.

### Problem

Following my code cleanup and performance improvements I got the macro to start at around 10 seconds per user, which is an excellent speed.  I let the macro run overnight last night and came in this morning to see it is now taking around 90 seconds per user, so I am experiencing a large degradation in performance overnight.

**My question is:  How can I prevent this slowdown from occurring as the macro runs over time?**

### Research

I am not without an idea.  Currently, my thoughts are that I would need to close and re-open the Excel workbooks because they are getting bogged down in garbage.  One idea I have is to perhaps use a native VB.NET application to open the Excel workbook and run the macros.  Every 500 or so users I could write the relevant variables somewhere in cells in the workbook, save and close the workbook, and then re-open it to pick up where I left off.  That doesn't seem very elegant to me.  Additionally, it may be difficult to convince others I need to introduce a "new" technology (VB.NET).  People are weird about that, and prefer a native VBA solution.

Is there a better way to manage Excel so that I don't have to create a new VB.NET application and do the saving/closing/opening?

I would like to add there is no specific offending code, it simply slows down (still works!) as time goes on.

Comment: I think we need some code to inspect, to help you out, as excel normally garbage collects stuff you don't use anymore. hence slowing down, is usually due to searching an array that increases in size, or looping over a sheet that increases in size, etc..

Comment: Alright, I have some meetings this morning, afterwards I can pull some code out of the project.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't see why you need vb.net: Why don't you use a VBA controlling application that opens the workbook, runs it for 500 users, saves it then closes and reopens it etc?

Comment: This is very true.  I inexplicably jumped right to VB.NET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few basic things that can help, I'm sure you've already tried most:

- Set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`
- Set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
- Set `Application.EnableEvents = False`

  ---

*A note on the above, always work with the assumption your code will fail and ensure an appropriate error handler is in place to reset these settings back to their defaults*

---

- Use `DoEvents` to return control to the processor now and again, there may be some processes building up that need to be completed to free up resources.
- Use direct boolean comparisons where possible.

Instead of:

```
If someVar > 5 Then
    boolVar = True
Else
    boolVar = False
End If
```

consider using

```
boolVar = someVariable > 5
```

- If you have to use If/Else syntax, see if a `Select Case` statement would be more appropriate.
- Use User-Defined Functions (UDFs) instead of repeating code
- Always avoid loops where possible, when working with ranges there is almost always another way (consider AutoFilter for example).
- Use worksheet functions if they already exist (e.g. `WorksheetFunction.SumIf()`) - don't re-invent the wheel!
- Look for any instances of things like `.Select` and get rid, you can access an object's properties and methods directly without selecting it.
- Use `Application.Goto` instead of `.Activate` where possible.
- Release objects from memory when they aren't required anymore e.g.
  `Set myObjectVar = Nothing`
- Use `vbNullString` instead of `""`